# Limit when x tends to 1

Tags: limits

[image: Limit when x tends to 1]

Dear friends. I would like to enlist the help of you in this question. I tried to improve the algebric expression, I tried the L'Hospital theorem, but nothing worked.

Grateful for your help. Big hug to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=y^6$. We are interested in the limit as $y\to 1$ of 
$$\frac{1}{2(1-y^3)}-\frac{1}{3(1-y^2)}.$$
Bring to the common denominator $(2)(3)(1-y^2)(1-y^3)$. The numerator is $3(1-y^2)-2(1-y^3)$. There is an obvious factor of $1-y$ on top. Simplify. There is an additional slightly hidden factor of $1-y$.

Comment: Dear André Nicolas, is the answer 1/12?

Comment: Yes. After the simplification we have $\frac{1+2y}{6(1+y)(1+y+y^2)}$.